# OOM kills and swappiness for IoT devices with eMMC and SD storage?

Tags: linux, sd-card, swap, arm, iot

I experience an occasional Out-of-Memory (OOM) kill from the compiler on BeagleBoards, CubieTrucks, etc. They are IoT devices, powered by ARM, generally have 512 MB to 2 GB of RAM, and use 4 or 8 GB of eMMC and SD card storage. They often lack a swap file due to characteristics of the underlying storage technology.

I've found a lot of information with respect to desktops and servers, but not IoT devices.

I also realize the extra writes decrease the lifetime of the media.

What the recommendations are for swappiness with respect to BeagleBoards, CubieTrucks, etc?

Comment: Very slow on writes (and relative low write life count) does not suggest SWAP at all, but if possible tight memory management in the application avoiding memory exhaustion (would be my recommendation, but I am a coder ;-)

Comment: @Dilettant - Theses devices don't use a swap file by default. I want to experiment with a swap file because I'm running out of RAM. There's nothing I can do about OOM kills in `cc1plus` (I've also tried other things, like avoiding `-pipe`). I've also [reported the issue](http://bugs.linaro.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1997) to Linaro. There's nothing they can do either.

Comment: I used a tiny swap with an eMMC equipped Yocto Linux driven device - but it was so tiny, I did neither profit from outOfRAMbutStillInSwap situations =() nor was I interested in what it does to the physical health.

Comment: Why not cross-compile on your PC?

Comment: @DanielB - It depends on the library being tested. Crypto++ is easy (it has documented procedures); OpenSSL is not so easy (it does not have official, documented procedures). To avoid the problems with cross-compiling, I just SSH into a device and perform the native build. The other choice is [Debian Chroot's](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/Debian_Chroot) on the host machine, which are up to 10x slower.

Comment: I suggest you look into Crosstool-ng. It worked well for me when I tried it a long time ago. It should make cross-compiling much easier.